# Поэтапный вывод строк в datagridview когда scroll окажется внизу

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

есть у меня winform datagridview. туда выводится 40 000 строк. занимает где-то 5-6 секунд. надо поэтапно загружать строки. например сначала загрузил 1000 строк. следующую партию загрузить когда скролл окажется внизу. каким способом это лучше сделать? с базой работаю через entityFramework.